# The function should return an array containing repetitions of the data arguments

Tags: python-2.7

My code does not pass some hidden tests,i need help

unit tests

```
def replicate_recur(a, b):
       #checking for correctness of 'a' type
       if not isinstance(a, int) and not isinstance(a, str):
           raise ValueError

       #checking for correctness of 'b' type
       if not isinstance(b, int) and not isinstance(b, str):
           raise ValueError

    #exit from function
       if a <= 0:
           return []

       res = replicate_recur(a - 1, b)

       res.append(b)

       #returning of result
       return res

    #iterative function
    def replicate_iter(a, b):
       #checking for correctness of 'a' type
       if not isinstance(a, int):
           raise ValueError

       res = []

       for i in range(a):
           res.append(b)

       return res

    a, b = (3,5)
    try:
       print replicate_recur(a, b)
    except ValueError:
       print "Wrong 'a or b' type"

    try:
       print replicate_iter(a, b)
    except ValueError:
       print "Wrong 'a or b' type"
```

Comment: `if not isinstance(a, int) and not isinstance(a, str)` so `a` can be a string, but at some point you're substracting `1` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it fully covers the "hidden tests" that we cannot guess but:

```
if not isinstance(a, int) and not isinstance(a, str):
```

why accepting `a` (or `b`) being a string?

If you let that pass, then you get `TypeError` when evaluating `a - 1`, which is different from `ValueError` (and before that `if a <= 0:` fails in python 3 with another `TypeError` exception)

Since `TypeError` isn't catched by your main program, the test probably fails.